# using an adfs SAML to autenticate linux login with ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, kerberos, adfs, pam

hello to everyone i'm here to ask if there is the possibility to use an ADFS to autenticate access to linux machine using ssh
many thanks

Comment: This is probably not on topic here, but it would be on Super User.  I'm not familiar with ADFS (so you should edit to define that term when you migrate), but I know Kerberos and SSH does work on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

This guide will cover how to configure Active Directory Federation Services ([ADFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory_Federation_Services)) to be a single sign-on (SSO) provider to issue SSH credentials to specific groups of users. When used in combination with role based access control (RBAC), it allows SSH administrators to define policies like:

- Only members of "DBA" group can SSH into machines running PostgreSQL.
- Developers must never SSH into production servers.
- ... and many others.

Complete solution is @ https://goteleport.com/docs/enterprise/sso/adfs/